# Has the search alert API in SharePoint 2013 changed from the 2010 and Preview 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, application-pages, 2013, search-api

I previously developed a Visual web part to programmatic-ally create Search alerts based on the user input. I used a text box to capture the text and create a Query using the Keyword Query Class. Then I used a constructor provided through the DLL/API, (THIS WAS IN SHAREPOINT 2010)

```
SearchAlert NewSearchAlert = new SearchAlert(SPSite xxx, Query xxxx )
```

This constructor was avilable in Sharepoint 2010 and Sharepoint 2013 Preview. But i cant not find this condtructor in Sharepoint 2013.

The available constructor in Sharepoint 2013 is

```
SearchAlert NewSearchAlert = new SearchAlert(SPAlertCollection xxx, SpAlert xxxx )
```

Is there someone who has worked with this class to tell me where i can find the Initial constructor where i pass the query and build the search alert or is there anyone who knows how to set the query text in an SPAlert and create a search alert using the new constructor?